# Lambda function

Tags: python, lambda

Why these two have different result?

input:

```
print((lambda x: x**2 + 5*x + 4) (-4))
```

output:

```
0
```

input:

```
print(lambda x: x**2 + 5*x + 4, -4)
```

output:

```
<function <lambda> at 0x00ECD588> -4
```

Answer (score 3):

The first one:

```
print((lambda x: x**2 + 5*x + 4) (-4))
```

This is:

- Make a function `(lambda x: x**2 + 5*x + 4)`
- Call the function with `(-4)` as an argument
- Print the result: `0`

---

The second one:

```
print(lambda x: x**2 + 5*x + 4, -4)
```

This is:

- Make a function `lambda x: x**2 + 5*x + 4`
- Print the function: `<function <lambda> at 0x1071230d0>` ...
- ... followed by the number `-4`